# How to clear server.log in JBoss?

Tags: java, linux, jboss, log4j, logfiles

How do I clear JBoss' server.log file when **JBoss is running**? When I try to do

```
echo 1 > server.log
```

I get error msg that the **file is being used** by another program (JBoss). Is it possible to use a command-line tool (**windows** or **linux**(I do have **CygWin**)) or an application that I can write myself to clear that file?

P.S. I don't need that file to have 0kb, but I want it to have **less than 100MB**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default JBoss keeps the file locked, since it is writing log messages into it. It is locked as long as JBoss is running and I don't know of other way to release it than stopping JBoss itself.

To keep its size under control, you can modify your log configuration, which is by default in `<server>/conf˛jboss-log4j.xml`. You can specify the maximum size of a log file, and define what to do when that size is reached: roll over to a new file, truncate the existing one and start writing over it again, etc.

A basic example (not tested, so no guarantee that it works straight as it is):

```
    <appender name="ROLL" class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
            ...
            <param name="maxFileSize" value="100MB" />
            ...
    </appender>
```

Moreover, with the `maxBackupIndex` parameter you may define the number of backup files (default is 1).

Answer (score 1):

JBoss locks the file as long as the logging process is running.

If you enabled the JMX console you can stop the logging, delete / modify the log, and start the logging service again.

The url should look something like this (for log4j):

http://jboss.example.com:8080/jmx-console/HtmlAdaptor?action=inspectMBean&name=jboss.system%3Atype%3DLog4jService%2Cservice%3DLogging

I tested this with JBoss 5.

This solution should be scriptable as well.

Regarding your log file size problem: You should use a configuration approach instead of editing the log file manually.

Answer (score 0):

To clear logs in JBoss, you can follow these steps:

1. Stop the JBoss Server: Before you clear the logs, it's a good practice to stop the JBoss server to prevent any potential issues while the logs are being cleared.
2. Navigate to the Log Directory: Locate the directory where JBoss/WildFly stores its log files. This directory is typically named standalone/log or domain/servers/server-name/log within your JBoss/WildFly installation directory.
3. Clear the log file
4. Start the JBoss Server: After you've cleared the logs, you can start the JBoss server again.

Comment: any chatgpt involved in this answer?